# Doctrine Criteria query with contains expression on a ManyToOne entity field

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, criteria

Considering two entities (with a ManyToOne relationship), is it possible to do something like this ?

**ENTITY: CLIENTE**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="cliente")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Cliente {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_cliente", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $nome;
    // getters, setters, etc...
}
```

**ENTITY: PEDIDO**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="pedido")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Pedido {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_pedido", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cliente")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_cliente", referencedColumnName="id_cliente")
     */
    private $cliente;
    // getters, setters, etc...
}
```

**EXAMPLE QUERY:**

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->contains('cliente.nome', 'Felippe'));
$pedidos = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Admin\Models\Pedido')->matching($criteria);
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> Unrecognized field: cliente.nome

I wrote a utility class to handle with jQuery Datatables search... And I'm trying to create a function on a Generic DAO to handle with it...

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks!